# Generating values from Normal distribution using Box-Muller method

Tags: python, math, probability

I'm writing a small function to generate values from the Normal distribution using Box-Muller method, but I'm getting negative values.

Here is my source code

```
import random

def generate_normal(mu, sigma):
    u = random.random()
    v = random.random()

    z1 = sqrt(-2 * log(u)) * sin(2 * pi * v)
    z2 = sqrt(-2 * log(u)) * cos(2 * pi * v)

    x1 = mu + z1 * sigma
    x2 = mu + z2 * sigma

    return x2
```

**Waht am I missing?** I'm getting negative values in both `x1` and `x2`. For example:

```
mu: 400
sigma: 150
u: 7.27333176449e-05
v: 0.642384573173
z1: -3.40497345242
x1: -110.746017863
```

and:

```
x2: -9.79324023117
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unit [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is centred on zero, and two-sided with small tails out to plus and minus infinity. [99.7% of your values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) will lie within three standard deviations, the other 0.3% won't.

[image]

In this example, with a mean of 400 and a standard deviation of 150, 99.7% of your values will fall within three standard deviations of the mean - the interval [-50,850], which includes negative numbers. So expect negative numbers right off the bat.

As for the other 0.3% of values, remember that's 3/1000 of your numbers - not uncommon at all.

If you want a "bell-curvey" distribution with finite support, try the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Finally, unless this is an academic exercise, there's no need to roll your own equivalent to [`numpy.random.normal()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).

Comment: Great. I don't know how I missed it. I was just focused on the problem, and I totally forgot that **very** famous graphic of N(0,1) `:)`. Thank you so much!

Comment: We all have our little lapses. ;) That said, any reason you're not using `numpy.random.normal()`?

Comment: OP isn't necessarily using NumPy at all, but the standard library offers this as `random.gauss` (faster but not threadsafe) or `random.normalvariate`. That said, IIRC the given method is prone to numerical instability (it's better to choose random coordinates in a unit square and reject them if they're outside the unit square, rather than choosing a weighted-random radius and random angle), and is throwing away half the valid results (`x1` is as random as `x2`, and independent; better to remember this value and return it every other time, or use a generator and `yield` both values in a loop).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm doing exactly that. I'm using `yield` so that I can return `x1`, `x2`, then generate two new ones, and repeat the process. @Li-aungYip I'm developing a simulation of an airport for academic purposes, and the idea is to implement the used distributions from scratch (Normal, Poisson and Exponential). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Box-Muller transformation has stability problems when the random generated value is very close to zero. I recommend to replace random.random() by gaussinan distribution and affect by your mean and standard deviation.